# iOS autolayout: get width of views inside a view in ViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios8, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I need to get the width of a `UIView` (B) inside other (A) at the time the ViewController is launched (in the image I have attached B is the UIView selected and the parents (A) is the UIView with white border). I am using autolayout so the UIView (B) has trailing and leading space to his parent (A)

[image]

I am trying to get the real width in viewDidLayoutSubview:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    NSLog(@"Layout %f --- %f --- %f ",self.oksPanel.frame.size.width,self.oksBar.frame.size.width);
    double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //code to be executed on the main queue after delay
    NSLog(@"Layout %f --- %f --- %f ",self.oksPanel.frame.size.width,self.oksBar.frame.size.width);
    });
}
```

`oksPanel` is the parent UIView (A) and `oksBar` is the child (B). The first `NSLog` prints the following:

```
Layout 538.000000 --- 378.000000
```

First number is ok, but the second is the width of the child UIView in the Interface Builder, not after setting contraints. However, when the code delayed is executed I get the correct numbers:

```
Layout 538.000000 --- 508.000000
```

What delegate method I have to call in order to get the right dimensions of the child UIView?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried viewDidAppear?

Comment: yes, I have tried it too

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem and fixed it by moving the subview (B) one level up, as a direct child of the ViewController's view, making it a sibling of (A). In this configuration, `ViewController.viewDidLayoutSubviews` will have the constraint-based bounds for both (A) & (B).

To illustrate, the original layout was:

```
ViewController.view
  -> (A)
    -> (B)
```

And my new layout is:

```
ViewController.view
  -> (A)
  -> (B)
```

---

(**Note: this section is untested**) If the `ViewController.view -> (A) -> (B)` hierarchy is required, maybe you can create a custom UIView for (A) and override a UIView callback to get the bounds. My first guess would be:

```
class CustomViewA: UIView {
   @IBOutlet weak var subviewB: UIView!

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let setBounds = subviewB.bounds
        // Do stuff with bounds...
    }
}
```

I think this because the [UIView.layoutSubviews docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20170104233901/https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews) specify:

> the default implementation uses any constraints you have set to determine the size and position of any subviews.

So I assume the subview bounds will be set after calling `super.layoutSubviews`.